# How to avoid code duplication without turning to boolean switch parameter?

Tags: java

I just found the following code:

```
public ThingId foo1(Map<String, Object> properties) {
  checkSomething();
  validateA(properties);
  validateB(properties);
  ...
  validateX(properties);
  return createTheThing(properties);
}
```

and

```
public ThingId foo2(Map<String, Object> properties, MoreStuff stuff) {
  checkSomething();
  validateB(properties);
  ...
  validateX(properties);
  return createTheThing(properties, stuff);
}
```

So the two method bodies were almost identical, besides `foo2()` not calling `validateA()`.

Trying to reduce code duplication, I turned to

```
private void checkAndValidate(Map<String, Object> properties, booelean validateA) {
  checkSomething();
  if (validateA) {
    validateA();
  }
  validateB(properties);
  ...
  validateX(properties);
}
```

So that `foo1()` and `foo2()` can both use that new method. But I really dislike that boolean parameter there.

Any idea, anybody?

Comment: What do you dislike about the boolean?

Comment: @UnholySheep I am a clean code enthusiast. Three parameters is like a no go, and such boolean thingies even more.

Comment: Somewhat depends on the context. For example, I could imagine this being a method and having such parameters as a class attribute, provided that a class is reasonable in the context. That said, maybe we should start at the opposite side - how do you would want the code to look like? Supposed that you could do any chance to the syntax of java that you wish.

Comment: You already have some decision logic that decides when to call *foo1()* and when *foo2()*. Is it possible to push that decision down to the validation methods?
- Just take a look where and how you determine the boolean parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the validations in a new method:

```
private void foo3(Map<String, Object> properties) {
  validateB(properties);
  ...
  validateX(properties);    
}


public ThingId foo1(Map<String, Object> properties) {
  checkSomething();
  validateA(properties);
  foo3(properties);
  return createTheThing(properties);

}

public ThingId foo2(Map<String, Object> properties,MoreStuff stuff) {
  checkSomething();
  foo3(properties);
  return createTheThing(properties,stuff);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Kinda; as there is still some duplication left. And I would make that new method private ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Yes there are 2 dupplicate lines. But you will not solve it without duplicate code and without boolean parameter. if the order of the method call is not important, you can also put the call of `checkSometing` also to foo3. But the call of foo3 is already a duplicate.

Comment: Not sure if you care, but I am kinda thinking about deleting this question; too many downvotes by now. As you answered already, maybe you want to help changing my mind by upvoting the stupid thing ...

Answer (score 2):

Nice question! I also wonder about this.
Below is what I usually do, not the best but can reduce a half times call method with boolean parameter.

```
private void checkAndValidate(Map<String, Object> properties, booelean validateA) {
  checkSomething();
  if (validateA) {
    validateA();
  }
  validateB(properties);
  ...
  validateX(properties);
}

private void checkAndValidate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    checkAndValidate(properties, false);
}
```

Comment: What is the diffrence to the solution of the OP?

Comment: Not sure if you care, but I am kinda thinking about deleting this question; too many downvotes by now. As you answered already, maybe you want to help changing my mind by upvoting the stupid thing ...